# asp table query

Tags: asp.net

The following code creates a box around further code I have on my website, this box has a grey border around it and I would like to delete it, also I would like both the text and grouping text to be centred. Does anyone know how I can do this.

Thanks
Ross

`<asp:Panel ID="Add_pnl" runat="server" GroupingText="Add Principal" Width="100%" Font-Names="verdana"
            Font-Size="Small" BackColor="white" align=center" BorderStyle="none" BorderColor="white">`

Comment: What have you tried? It would be helpful to show the rendered HTML source code. This code doesn't produce any styling, the rendered HTML does.

Comment: If I remove the GroupingText code, then the border dissapears, is there anyway I can keep this but just keep the "Add Principle" part?

Answer (score 0):

`GroupingText` simply adds a `fieldset` with `legend` into the rendered `div` element. Therefore you can do the following to change the border styles of these elements:

Add a `CssClass` property to your `Panel`:

```
<asp:Panel CssClass="myPanel" ... />
```

Then add the following CSS:

```
.myPanel fieldset
{
  border:0;
}
.myPanel fieldset legend
{
  border:0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but when I do this I get a parse error on `.myPanel fieldset` you see the page doesn't have any html in it at all, no head or body

Comment: @Ross It might be worth you adding more information to your question. I can't tell what skill level you have.